# How to different calculation on different granularity?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to achieve the following:

[image: example]

The idea is to calculate the sum product in the following scenario:

- When calculating the **subtotal** (that is on the Level1 granularity) the formula is: the **sum of Wieght2 * Amount**.
- When calculating the **grand total**, the formula is: the **sum of Wieght1 * subtotal**.

**How can I achieve that in DAX?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how your data model looks...

With a model like this:

[image]

Your DAX measure may look something like this:

```
Weighted Amount = 
    SWITCH ( 
        TRUE(),
        ISINSCOPE ( Level2[Level 2] ), 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Level2[Amount] ),
        ISINSCOPE ( Level1[Level 1] ),
        SUMX ( 
            Level2,
            Level2[Amount] * Level2[Weight 2]
        ),
        SUMX ( 
            Level1,
            CALCULATE ( 
                SUMX ( 
                    Level2,
                    Level2[Amount] * Level2[Weight 2]
                )
            ) * Level1[Weight 1]
        )
    )
```

We're using `SWITCH` and `ISINSCOPE` to determine the level at which the measure is being evaluated, then following your business logic for each level.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... that is very helpful ... but what if the Amount column by it self is a measure?

Comment: Then replace the column reference ( `Level2[Amount]` ) with the Measure reference ( `[Amount]` ), and remove the `SELECTEDVALUE` function.